# Pandas: Set MultiColumn values based on flat columned value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a MultiColumned data-frame as follows:

```
Out[1]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(price, mean), (price, mom_2), (units, mean), (units, mom_2)]
Index: []
```

I have some (flat) values for `mean`, which I would like to put into `price` and `units`:

```
>>> value
Out[2]: 
price    0.0
units    0.0
dtype: float64
```

I thought the way to go was

```
resultsDf.loc[idx, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'mean']] = value
```

but it wasn't, as the values weren't taken over:

```
resultsDf.loc
                                     price       units      
                                      mean mom_2  mean mom_2
(desc, foo) (desc, bar)                        
1500002071               65            NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I guess, on further inspection, the problem is that despite me selecting based on the first level, I still have a multi-leveled left hand side, which I cannot merge/paste into from a single-leveled right hand side:

```
>>> resultsDf.loc[idx, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'mean']]
Out[5]: 
price  mean    NaN
units  mean    NaN
Name: (1500002071, 65), dtype: object
>>> value
Out[6]: 
price    0.0
units    0.0
dtype: float64
```

What's the way to go here?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the selection with `IndexSlice` keeps the levels. I don't know of any neat method here (if at all it exists).

A safe workaround would be to reindex the series:

```
value.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([value.index, ['mean']])
resultsDf.loc[idx] = value
```

Alternatively (but may be risky), if you are sure the orders of columns in the frame and rows in the series are the same, then this should also work:

```
resultsDf.loc[idx, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'mean']] = value.tolist()
```